# Visual Studio 2012 error MSB3073

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to upgrade just my IDE, not the compiler yet, from Visual studio 2010 to 2012. I keep getting

`Error  9   error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\..\IDE\devenv" mdlibs.sln /Build "Release|x64"" exited with code 1.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   38  lib_mdlibs (Visual Studio 2008)`

It directs me to this code

```
 <Target Name="Build" 
     DependsOnTargets="PrepareForNMakeBuild;ResolveReferences;GetTargetPath" 
     Returns="$(NMakeManagedOutput)">

    <VCMessage Code="MSB8005" Type="Warning" Arguments="NMakeBuildCommandLine" 
          Condition="'$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)'==''"/>

    <Exec Command="$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)"  
          Condition="'$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)'!=''"/>
 </Target>
```

Specifically the second last line

I have no idea how to deal with this! I've tried a few things but nothing so far has worked

When I build just lib_mdlibs  it says
The operation could not be completed

```
1>  
1>  Use:
1>  devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | anyfile.ext]  [switches]
1>  
1>  The first argument for devenv is usually a solution file or project file.
1>  You can also use any other file as the first argument if you want to have the
1>  file open automatically in an editor. When you enter a project file, the IDE
1>  looks for an .sln file with the same base name as the project file in the
1>  parent directory for the project file. If no such .sln file exists, then the
1>  IDE looks for a single .sln file that references the project. If no such single
1>  .sln file exists, then the IDE creates an unsaved solution with a default .sln
1>  file name that has the same base name as the project file.
```

I thought maybe it was my Command line Build which is

`"$(VS110COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\devenv" mdlibs.sln /Build "$(Configuration)|$(Platform)"`

But I've tried changing it a couple of time and nothing really helps

I tried opening the just the mdlibs solution in vs2012 and building that, but when I try to build it I get a pop up that says the project file ' ' has been renamed or is no longer in the solution

Or if I try to build any of the individual projects in mdlibs.sln it says cannot perform requested action because a build is already in progress, even if I had just opened the solution

Any suggestions? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated I'm completely stuck

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because vc11 vcvars get setup as default. Go to VS2010 -> VS Tools -> VS Command Prompt (2010) & then execute your command there.

If above works, execute the 2010 vcvars.bat from the command prompt before executing devenv.exe or msbuild.exe.